# A is symmetric iff A=P-Q, where P,Q are positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

*Show that an $n \times n$ real matrix $A$ is symmetric iff $A$ can be written as $$A=P-Q$$ where $P$ and $Q$ are some $n \times n$ positive definite matrices. Can there be anything said  similarly about complex $n \times n$ matrices?*

**Attempt:** Clearly if $A=P-Q$, it is symmetric. Conversely, suppose $A$ is symmetric. Then $$A=R^{-1}DR$$ where $D=$diag$\lbrace \lambda_1,...\lambda_n \rbrace, \lambda_i \in \mathrm{R}$ so $$A=R^{-1}D_1R - R^{-1}D_2R$$ where $D_1=$diag$\lbrace \alpha_1,...\alpha_n \rbrace$ and $D_2=$diag$\lbrace \mu_1,...\mu_n\rbrace$ where $$\lambda_i = \alpha_i-\mu_i \quad s.t. \quad \alpha_i,\mu_i >0$$
We know that the last statement is possible, since the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ are real numbers.

We cannot conclude the same about complex $n \times n$ matrices.

**I am not sure if there is more to this than what I proved above.**

Comment: Did you mean to impose as well the condition that $P$ and $Q$ be symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

For the complex case, substitute "hermitian" for "symmetric"